# Which major airport close to Pacific Northwest has a cinema showing "Ghost In The Shell" close by?

Tags: airports, north-america, cinema

[Ghost In The Shell](http://www.funimationfilms.com/movie/ghostintheshell/) is back in some theatres. I might fly down to see it (I am Vancouver based). But I do not drive and so I'd rather have a theatre close to the airport and easily accessible by transit.

Which airport to pick?

Comment: Amtrak?  They have many more stops than the airlines.

Comment: I *think* the closest with Amtrak is in Seattle and Amtrak is woefully slow.

Comment: Remember the return trip after the movie is over.

Comment: @MichaelHampton that's *exactly* why I need a theatre close to the airport, to make a return trip the same day feasible. I cut through security and border queues with the NEXUS card and I obviously would have no checked luggage so the airport wait time is low.

Comment: How is this on topic?  There could be dozens of answers, with massive difference in prices between them.  WANTA!

Comment: I didn't ask about prices. Also, last I checked there are no "dozens" of USA airports with flights from Vancouver. There's SEA, PDX, DFW,DEN, PHX, HNL, LAX, ATL, DTW, JFK, EWR, MSP, ORD, SLC, IAH, LAS, SNA, PSP, SAN - 19 all.

Comment: You forgot ANC, DTW, OGG, KOA, LIH, MCO, SFO, SJC, IAD. Which I believe puts us into the realms of "dozens", no? Those might or might not be "close" depending on your definition, but again we're into the territory of opinion based.  (Airport list based details on the YVR website)

Comment: Sigh. To give you an idea: HKG has an IMAX theatre inside the airport. I think SIN too. In the USA, Lancaster (LNS) has one <15 min walk away -- pity there's practically no flights to there and it's easy coast anyways. The question is hardly WANTA even if we manage to find ~30 airports because the question is not which airport is cheap to fly but: out of the set of airports which has a movie theatre accessible by public transit within, say, 30 (or less) minutes which one is closest to YVR? The cardinality of said set will be extremely small...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest and easiest option for you is to take a bus down to Seattle, which has two cinemas showing the movie:

[image]

There are also plenty of direct flights if you were so inclined.